# How to locate compressed bits of certain files in a zip archive for further processing?

Tags: c#, c, compression, zlib

Context:
To save more space, I want to further compress some files in a zip archive with an algorithm, and other files in same archive with another algorithm. Later I need to revert the process to get the **original** zip archive, because the zip files are owned by users.

How to locate compressed bits of certain files in a zip archive for further processing?

Language: Guess this kind of code is usually C/C++ for performance, but C# is good too.

OS: Windows Server 2012 R2 or later.

**Edit:**
I learned that in zip(**zlib**) format, compressed files are organized in blocks. We should be able to locate the files by searching headers. Still checking on how to code it.

Comment: Nope. The only available operations on zip archives, from common libraries that operate them, are to extract their contents, or create new ones. That's it. If you want to search the contents of the zip file, it's up to you to use the existing libraries to read and extract the contents, and search them yourself. After that, your only option is to create a new, replacement, zip archive with any modifications.

Comment: There is no such language as "C/C++".

Answer (score -1):

The zip file format is fully documented. e.g. http://www.fileformat.info/format/zip/corion.htm
You can find other sources and descriptions easily.

What you have to do is to read bytes according to the format and you have exact knowledge about where a certain file's compressed bits are. You can find open source libraries for this or you can roll your own in your preferred language.

As a side note, compressing an otherwise compressed file in a zip archive may not worth the efforts.

Comment: Thanks @PepitoSh. Could you list some good libraries that can locate compressed files (bits) by file name or other criteria? Or even better, example code.^^

Comment: I use DotNetZip for my needs: http://dotnetzip.codeplex.com I never had to dig down to bit level but I am sure you can find that part in this great open source project.